# Ruby on Rails Mi aplicación en producción no me muestra la información completa Render JSON Serializer

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, api, ruby, serialización

tengo un problema muy raro en mi aplicación en ruby on rails, estoy codificando una API. El problema radica principalmente en un Controlador que referencia a un modelo de negocios el cual a su vez tiene relación con sucursales y este a su vez con otras tablas. El problema principal es que al mandar a llamar a un negocio en especifico en localhost:

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/businesses/22

Esto me trae los datos correctos y completos:

```
  {
  "id": 22,
  "name": "El Culiacancito de Noche",
  "description": "",
  "friendly_url": "el-culiacancito-de-noche",
  "logo_url_string": null,
  "subcategory_id": 512,
  "business_package_id": 1,
  "icon_default": "res.cloudinary.com/plif-mx/image/upload/v1461337461/iconcategories/imagen.jpg",
  "branches": [
    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Sucursal - El Culiacancito de Noche",
      "friendly_url": null,
      "headquarter": null,
      "user_id": null,
      "location": {
        "id": 22,
        "street": "",
        "number": "",
        "neighborhood": "",
        "zip": "34080",
        "municipality": null,
        "num_int": null,
        "references": null
      },
      "geolocation": {
        "id": 22,
        "lat": "24.040599822998047",
        "lng": "-104.65699768066406"
      },
      "phones": [
        {
          "id": 15,
          "number": "+526181452555",
          "ext": null
        }
      ],
      "schedules": [],
      "rating": 0
    }
  ],
  "category_image_cover": "res.cloudinary.com/plif-mx/image/upload/v1461337460/covercategories/imagen.jpg",
  "category_image_logo": "res.cloudinary.com/plif-mx/image/upload/v1461337461/iconcategories/imagen.jpg",
  "rating_total": 0
}
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es al momento que hago deploy en el servidor y al consultar el mismo negocio no me sale la información completa en las sucursales solo me muestra la información de esa tabla y de las demás que tienen relación con ella no me trae nada.

```
{
  "id": 22,
  "name": "El Culiacancito de Noche",
  "description": "",
  "friendly_url": "el-culiacancito-de-noche",
  "logo_url_string": null,
  "subcategory_id": 512,
  "business_package_id": 1,
  "icon_default": "res.cloudinary.com/plif-mx/image/upload/v1461337461/iconcategories/imagen.jpg",
  "branches": [
    {
      "id": 22,
      "headquarter": null,
      "business_id": 22,
      "user_id": null,
      "created_at": "2016-04-19T16:45:54.000-05:00",
      "updated_at": "2016-04-19T16:45:54.000-05:00",
      "name": "Sucursal - El Culiacancito de Noche",
      "friendly_url": null
    }
  ],
  "category_image_cover": "res.cloudinary.com/plif-mx/image/upload/v1461337460/covercategories/imagen.jpg",
  "category_image_logo": "res.cloudinary.com/plif-mx/image/upload/v1461337461/iconcategories/imagen.jpg",
  "rating_total": 0
}
```

En seguida coloco el código que esta generando este json y a su vez los serializars

Metodo show que trae los datos del negocio y los renderea a json

```
def show
  render json: BusinessSerializer.new(Business.find(params[:id]))
end
```

Serializer de negocios

```
 class Api::V1::BusinessSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

   has_many :branches
   attributes :id, :name, :description, :friendly_url, :logo_url_string, :subcategory_id, :business_package_id, :icon_default, :branches
   attributes :category_image_cover, :category_image_logo
   attribute :get_rating_total, key: :rating_total


   def category_image_cover
     self.object.object.category_image.cover_url_url
   end

   def category_image_logo
     self.object.object.category_image.icon_url_url
   end
end
```

Serializer de Sucursales.

```
class Api::V1::BranchSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  belongs_to :business

  attributes :id, :name, :friendly_url, :headquarter, :user_id, :location, :geolocation, :phones, :schedules, :rating

  attribute :get_location, key: :location
  attribute :get_geolocation, key: :geolocation
  attribute :get_phones, key: :phones
  attribute :get_schedules, key: :schedules
  attribute :get_rating, key: :rating


  def get_location
    LocationSerializer.new(object.location)
  end

  def get_geolocation
    GeolocationSerializer.new(object.geolocation)
  end

  def get_phones
    object.phones.map {|p| PhoneSerializer.new(p)}
  end

  def get_schedules
    object.schedules.map {|s| ScheduleSerializer.new(s)}
  end

  class LocationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :street, :number, :neighborhood, :zip,
      :municipality, :num_int, :references
  end

  class GeolocationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :lat, :lng
  end

  class PhoneSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :number, :ext
  end

  class ScheduleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :open , :close_i , :open_i , :close , :day_id
  end

end
```

Comment: ¿Y has verificado que efectivamente están los datos existentes y relacionados en producción?

Comment: Si son las mismas bases de datos y de no tener los datos me lo mandaría nulo y ni eso me retorna. El código es el mismo también ya des instale todo el servidor y lo volví a crear y sigue el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es el mismo codigo en producción como en desarrollo tu problema esta en la base de datos, checa que la info de tu base de dato sea la misma.